# Getting from a string of bytes from this byte array

Tags: c#, java

at С# I have to I have an **array of bytes**(of two numbers - -0.2210166 and 1.41497) that I was placed in a string separated by commas:

```
String data = "47,82,98,190,188,29,181,63";
```

I get it:

```
protected BinaryWriter writer;

public void writeFloat(float val) {
    writer.Write (val);
}

public byte[] getBytes() {
    return buffer.ToArray ();
}
```

I am trying to get back this **array of bytes** at Java:

```
String[] array = data.split(",");

List<Byte> listOfBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
for (String str : array) {
    listOfBytes.add(Byte.valueOf(str));
}

Byte[] B = listOfBytes.toArray(new Byte[listOfBytes.size()]);

byte[] stateData = new byte[B.length];
for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    stateData[i] = B[i];
}
```

in this place I get an error that can't get a value greater than permissible in bytes:

```
listOfBytes.add(Byte.valueOf(str));
```

for example when ***str = 190*** from data. I understand why i got the error. But i dont understand why buffer at C# writes an array of 4 bytes, with these values, of which I can not get back his bytes.
Any ideas guys? I'm confused...

Comment: You are mixing a lot of things (strings with floats and bytes...), do you want to save it in binary, as a string...? what is the real purpose of this?

Comment: I suspect your issue is that a `byte` in Java is a *signed* 8bit type.

Comment: To mr. Brian Roach.
you are right, but as I then implement the receipt of bytes?

Comment: To mr.Gusman.
from C# I have an array of bytes, placed into a string to pass to java and ultimately from an array of bytes to get back their numbers (-0.2210166 and 1.41497)